# sql server return null in select when value is repeated

Tags: sql-server, select

i have a query returning user actions with action date , howeever , I want my query to return all the actions with their dates but return null for the action date when the date equals the previous date , for example

```
action                date
gone shopping         10/1/2011
swimming              10/1/2011
riding                11/1/2011

so i want my select to return rows like this
action                date
gone shopping         10/1/2011
swimming              NULL
riding                11/1/2011
```

anyone has an idea to implement this?

Comment: You need to clarify how you get your `ORDER` in the query, and post some sample code.

Comment: @Rami Shareef - What do you mean 'share your query' that's what he needs help with.  Please read the question.

Comment: @JonH: Hi said the data projecting in a way of duplication for the `date`, so that indicate he uses a query to get the data? Right?

Comment: @Rami - I read it as here's the data set, I want nulls on duplicate activities, so write the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a situation where you would want this aesthetic logic handled in the application layer, not the database layer.

It could cause issues if you change the order of records, or something downstream adds additional logic like a `GROUP BY`.

**It is generally a bad idea to remove data without a reason**.  You will be effectively uncoupling the `action` from the `date` for any other process that consumes your data downstream.

Comment: I am not uncoupling them but this is how I want to display my data.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this is because that's how you want to display the data?

In which case, do this in your user interface code, not in your SQL queries. It is possible using `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` but you'll end up with a very convoluted SQL query.

Comment: +1 - not the solution but I would do this in the presentation / report layer.

Comment: I just dont want to mess up my data access layer I am keeping it on a specific standard thats why I want to make this using the query.

Comment: You will mess up your data access layer by putting view logic in it. That's what we're saying.

Comment: Tim this is what I am saying so what is the suitable solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table
(
  [action] varchar(20),
  [date] date
)

insert into @T
select 'gone shopping', '10/1/2011' union all
select 'swimming',      '10/1/2011' union all
select 'riding',        '11/1/2011'

;with cte as
(
  select [action],
         [date],
         row_number() over(order by [date], [action]) as rn
  from @T
)
select C1.[action],
       case when C2.[date] is null
         then C1.[date]
       end as [date]   
from cte as C1
  left outer join cte as C2
    on C1.rn = C2.rn + 1 and
       C1.[date] = C2.[date]
order by C1.rn
```